# C# deep copy list<T>

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, deep-copy, binaryformatter

I'm trying to deep copy some lists.
I use the System.Runtime.Serialization to copy the object while it appeared this error:
System.ArgumentNullException: 'Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'graph')'

Thanks so much!!

the clone Methond

```
public static T Clone<T>(T RealObject)
        {
            using (Stream objectStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                //利用 System.Runtime.Serialization序列化与反序列化完成引用对象的复制
                IFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
                formatter.Serialize(objectStream, RealObject);
                objectStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                return (T)formatter.Deserialize(objectStream);
            }
        }
```

the example

```
private void AddVariant()
    {
        ShouldRender();
        Count++;

        VKDTI VKDTI = KeyInfoMethod.GetNewVKDTI();
        VKDTI.Variant = Count.ToString();

        //l_VKDTI_TSI.Add(l_VKDTI_TSI.FirstOrDefault());
        l_VKDTI_TSI_Copy.Add(KeyInfoMethod.Clone<VKDTI_TSI>(l_VKDTI_TSI.FirstOrDefault()));
        l_VKDTI_VI_Copy.Add(KeyInfoMethod.Clone<VKDTI_VI>(l_VKDTI_VI.FirstOrDefault()));
        l_VKDTI_DIMENSIONS_Copy.Add(KeyInfoMethod.Clone<VKDTI_DIMENSIONS>(l_VKDTI_DIMENSIONS.FirstOrDefault()));
        l_VKDTI_VW_Copy.Add(KeyInfoMethod.Clone<VKDTI_VW>(l_VKDTI_VW.FirstOrDefault()));
        l_VKDTI_ENGINE_Copy.Add(KeyInfoMethod.Clone<VKDTI_ENGINE>(l_VKDTI_ENGINE.FirstOrDefault()));
        l_VKDTI_TRANSMISSION_Copy.Add(KeyInfoMethod.Clone<VKDTI_TRANSMISSION>(l_VKDTI_TRANSMISSION.FirstOrDefault()));
        l_VKDTI_DRIVETRAIN_Copy.Add(KeyInfoMethod.Clone<VKDTI_DRIVETRAIN>(l_VKDTI_DRIVETRAIN.FirstOrDefault()));
        l_VKDTI_TAW_Copy.Add(KeyInfoMethod.Clone<VKDTI_TAW>(l_VKDTI_TAW.FirstOrDefault()));
        l_VKDTI_HUMP_Copy.Add(KeyInfoMethod.Clone<VKDTI_HUMP>(l_VKDTI_HUMP.FirstOrDefault()));
        l_VKDTI_WAP_Copy.Add(KeyInfoMethod.Clone<VKDTI_WAP>(l_VKDTI_WAP.FirstOrDefault()));
        l_VKDTI_PEDAL_Copy.Add(KeyInfoMethod.Clone<VKDTI_PEDAL>(l_VKDTI_PEDAL.FirstOrDefault()));
        l_VKDTI_BOOSTER_Copy.Add(KeyInfoMethod.Clone<VKDTI_BOOSTER>(l_VKDTI_BOOSTER.FirstOrDefault()));
        l_VKDTI_MC_Copy.Add(KeyInfoMethod.Clone<VKDTI_MC>(l_VKDTI_MC.FirstOrDefault()));
        l_VKDTI_FB_Copy.Add(KeyInfoMethod.Clone<VKDTI_FB>(l_VKDTI_FB.FirstOrDefault()));
        l_VKDTI_RB_Copy.Add(KeyInfoMethod.Clone<VKDTI_RB>(l_VKDTI_RB.FirstOrDefault()));
        l_VKDTI_OVI_Copy.Add(KeyInfoMethod.Clone<VKDTI_OVI>(l_VKDTI_OVI.FirstOrDefault()));
        l_VKDTI_Copy.Add(KeyInfoMethod.Clone<VKDTI>(l_VKDTI.FirstOrDefault()));

        if (l_ESPTI_VAF_ALL_SELECTED.Count > 0)
        {
            l_ESPTI_VAF_ALL_Copy.Add(KeyInfoMethod.Clone<ESPTI_VAF_ALL>(l_ESPTI_VAF_ALL.FirstOrDefault()));
            l_ESPTI_VAF_ALL_SELECTED_Copy.Add(KeyInfoMethod.Clone<ESPTI_VAF_ALL>(l_ESPTI_VAF_ALL_SELECTED.FirstOrDefault()));
        }

        StateHasChanged();
    }
```

Comment: Why not use the copy constructor for List<T>? e.g. 'new List<VKDTI_TSI>(l_VKDTI_TSI.FirstOrDefault())'

Comment: Don't use that code. [BinaryFormatter is disabled in ASP.NET Core applications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/core-libraries/5.0/binaryformatter-serialization-obsolete) and isn't coming back. That's an extremely insecure class and after of years of warnings, the .NET Core team is finally removing it.

Comment: This looks like a Blazor component with raw properties instead of a Model. I suspect you could get rid of cloning and simplify your code a *lot* if you refactored your components to use a model instead of fields and properties

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the documentation for [.Serialize](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.serialization.formatters.binary.binaryformatter.serialize?view=net-5.0) you can see that Null is not a valid value for the `graph` parameter. In your case that would be the `RealObject`.

So it seems likely that you are trying to serialize a null object. You are using `.FirstOrDefault()` in a bunch of places, and this will probably return null, causing the problem you observe. Fix by inserting a nullcheck.